# Can I have something like this when no internet connection is available?

Tags: android, mobile, android-notifications

[image]

Hi guys. I'm working on an app that only works over wifi. When no connection is available,I have a toast displayed saying no connection available, but the user can still press buttons, etc. I want something like this displayed as long as no internet connection is available.Is it possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to check your internet connection

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want a screen like your image above when there isn't a network connection? If so, that has to be one of the worst UI / UX designs I've ever seen.

Comment: Hi Squonk! Thank you for your post. Can I ask you why is it the worst UI/UX design you've ever seen? Any other ideeas on how to make the app unusable if there is no connection? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my method to check for conectivity:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    boolean connected = false;
    try {           
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
        return connected;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return connected;
}
```

You will use the method to show/hide the TextView with the message "`No connection Available`":

```
if(isOnline()){
    findViewById(R.id.no_internet).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) // Online
}else{
    findViewById(R.id.no_internet).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) // Disconnected
}
```

Comment: Hi Elenasys! Thanks for your post. Any idea why it throws an error on "Variables"Do I have to declare it? Thank you in advance

Comment: Oh. i´m sorry must be the application Context, I have edited my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can create layout something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <!-- your layout -->
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_internet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clicable="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No connection available"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And call

```
findViewById(R.id.no_internet).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

to show this view

Comment: Hi Vladimir! Thank you for your post. Tried your code and the Layout is still visible after the connection is back? Any ideeas why? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We usually have a default view of no connection available, and then when content is pulled down via Volley or OKHTTP and ready to be put into the views we want to display, we show those views and hide the no connection view. Works similarly to the progress spinner in the ListFragment code.